# How to get the end year of every school year vb.net

Tags: vb.net

For example I have the school year 2012-2013. I only want to get the "2013" same goes as school year 2016-2017 I only want "2017". Can anyone help me? i Know this is easy. But I dont have any idea on how. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have

```
Dim String str = "2012-2013"
```

Then by using `String.Split()`:

```
Dim strArr() As String
strArr = str.Split("-")
```

With `strArr` you will have:

```
'strArr(0) = "2012"`
'strArr(1) = "2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your school year data is all consistent you could use the 
`String.Substring(int, int)` method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

**Ex:**

```
    dim String schoolYear = "2012-2014"          
    schoolYear.Substring(5,4)
```

Should return `2014`